# the remote server returned an error (404) not found. at system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, asp.net-web-api

I was having ssl error so I have written some code to ignore ssl errors after that ssl errors closed, now it is throwing new error like the remote server returned an error `(404) not found`. at `System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
      new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
```

please help me in closing this error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used any redirect method which redirect your request from http to https even you have disabled it, review your code global or config file if you made any redirection from there.

Or may be you are using [RequireHttps] from where you are getting response.

Comment: No I haven't made any redirection,  i am working on firebase push notification using one url https://fcm.goggleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: Did you check with HTTP verbs, are you properly using in your web.config.